# When we have a compound subject or object, which relative pronoun should we use?

Tags: grammar

I know ‘who’ is used for people; ‘that’ is used for things or animals in restricting clauses; ‘which’ is used for nonrestrictive clauses (though, some people use ‘which’ even for restricted ones); and whose can be used for both (though, some people argue that should be used just for people).

No books explain what you can use for a compound subject or object formed by a person and a non specific animal.
(However, I know ‘who’ can be used for animals if the animal is a pet that is named and treated as a person.)

In a sentence in which the compound object is made by people and animals like the following one

“They scared every person and creature (…) stood in front of them.”

Which pronoun is correct: who or which.

Comment: Or 'that'. Or none of the above.

Comment: @ Astralbee—Thank you for your clear explanation! I thought this site was supposed to help, not to mock.

Comment: The site has a clear purpose - to answer questions about *learning* English. It's not a site full of people waiting to do your homework for you. A question like this is off-topic, really, because you haven't asked a question about English - you've just asked which is correct. No research. Have a read about defining and non-defining clauses, that will help.

Comment: Or you could get round it by saying "...standing in front of them".

Comment: @ Astralbee— First of all, I  am just a 54 years old who is learning English, reading and asking questions on the internet—I am Italian and never had the opportunity to study English in school.
I know ‘who’ is used for people; ‘that’ is used for things or animals in restricting clauses; ‘which’ is used for nonrestrictive clauses (though, some people use ‘which’ even for restricted ones); and whose can be used for both (though, some people argue that should be used just for people).

Comment: Wow, @Astralbee and Piermo, please assume the best of each other. I don't think that initial brief comment was meant as mockery, just a small contribution. Meanwhile, the question seems on-topic enough to me, and I doubt it would be easy to find a clear answer in research. Because to me it seems the problem with the question is that many of these usages are *not* set in stone. It seems like with each of the singular usages you mentioned, you also acknowledge that there's some disagreement or variation. I think the same would be true here. That said, I'd default to "who."

Comment: The subordinator "that" would avoid the problem of the antecedent containing a mixture of human and non-human nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“They scared every person and creature (…) stood in front of them.”

No need for who or which

“They scared every person and creature **standing** in front of them.”

This phrasing may not be one the OP was aware of.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about using a participle instead of a relative clause—though I read it’s preferred to use a relative clause whit a general reference—But I think that in this case your suggestion resolves the problem.

Comment: @Piermo Don't believe what you read. :) [it's preferable to use...]

Comment: @ Lambie. Thank you—preferable (adjective)—preferred (just verb’s past)—I should have checked. :)

Comment: @Piermo No worries. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

I would unhesitatingly use *that*.

I'm afraid that your premise "‘who’ is used for people; ‘that’ is used for things or animals in restricting clauses" is simply not true.

It wouldn't surprise me to hear that some book told you that (the rest of your sentence shows that you understand that there are a lot of "rules" promulgated by books and teachers, that have nothing to do with English)

It is true that *who* is more common for people; but *that* is perfectly good. The "News on the Web" corpus has about 15 times as many instances of "man who" as "man that" - but there are still forty thousand of the latter (659 483:43 508). For "person who/that" the ratio is only about 5:1 (398 796:71 817)